# How to compile vlc-qt libraries in BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: shared-libraries, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, libvlc, vlc-qt

I'd like to compile VLC-Qt for BeagleBoneBlack.

To do this, I did these steps:

1. first of all, I downloaded vlc-qt source codes from [here](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/releases).
2. then, I move these codes to /home/debian/vlc-qt-0.90.0,in BBB
3. I created a folder, named "qtvlc" in "vlc-qt-0.90.0" folder.
4. I moved Qt5.2 Beaglebone Binaries,to qt-5.2 folder in
   /home/debian/qt-5.2
5. added "SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/debian/qt-5.3.2") to
   vlc-qt-0.90.0/CMakeLists.txt
6. cd to /vlc-qt-0.90.0/qtvlc and then type cmake ..
7. make
8. make install
9. ldconfig -v

After doing these steps, Compilation successfully done and libraries successfully placed in /usr/local/lib folder.

This is my pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
##===================
INSTALLS += target
TARGET = beagleplot
target.files = beagleplot
target.path = /home/debian
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lVLCQtCore  -lVLCQtWidgets
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include
```

Now, when I'm trying to compile this project, I receive:

- > /usr/local/lib//libVLCQtCore.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
- > collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have to note that, other programs run fine on BBB. but when I add a path to VLC-qt libs I receive this error.

Please help me what should I do?